# Toggle mute button with parameters

Tags: javascript, button, parameters, boolean, toggle

I'm trying to make a bunch of toggle mute buttons. To prevent myself from writing a bunch of functions that all do the same thing I use parameters, and I think that is where the code messes up. To my knowledge this is supposed to work if I weren't using parameters.

```
let isMuted1 = false,
    isMuted2 = false,
    isMuted3 = false,
    isMuted4 = false,
    isMuted5 = false,
    isMuted6 = false,
    isMuted7 = false;

muteButton1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster1, audio1, isMuted1);
})
muteButton2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster2, audio2, isMuted2);
})
muteButton3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster3, audio3, isMuted3);
})
muteButton4.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster4, audio4, isMuted4);
})
muteButton5.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster5, audio5, isMuted5);
})
muteButton6.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster6, audio6, isMuted6);
})
muteButton7.addEventListener('click', () => {
    muteMonster(monster7, audio7, isMuted7);
})

function muteMonster(monster, audioElement, isMuted) {
    if (!isMuted) {
        isMuted = true;
        monster.style.opacity = "0.5";
        audioElement.muted = true;
    } else {
        isMuted = false;
        monster.style.opacity = "1";
        audioElement.muted = false;
    }
}
```

I tried making the toggle button by flicking a bool to false if it was true, and to true if it was false. Executing different code depending on the state of the bool. I had to do this for a bunch of buttons so I wrote only one function that takes in a different bool depending on what button you press.

(Also I'm sure there's a neater way to do what I'm trying to do but I'm a little pressed on time and wouldn't know how yet)

Comment: Where does the `audio1` etc. arguments comes from? Also your `isMuted` parameter to the `muteMonster` is scoped inside a function and that is not modifying the global `isMuted` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can move `isMuted`, `monster` and `audio` variables into DOM's attribute. So the button will keep its state (on/off), and the name of a corresponding monster and audio.

Create maps of monsters and audios where name of attribute corresponds to the variable. Then call `setButtonAttributes` to set names of audios and monsters as button attributes.

It is important that in `buttons` array you keep DOM objects, you can get them with methods like `document.getElementById("BUTTON_ID")`, `document.getElementsByTagName("button)`, etc.

```js
let buttons = [...] // here enumerate all your buttons
let monsters = {
    monster1: monster1, 
    monster2: monster2,...
} // keep your monster variables in a map
let audios = {
} // audios' map similar to monsters' one

for(let button of buttons) {
    button.onclick = () => muteMonster(button)
}

function muteMonster(button) {
    let monster = monsters[button.getAttribute("monster")]
    let audioElement = audios[button.getAttribute("audio")]
    if (!button.getAttribute("isMuted")) {
        button.setAttribute("isMuted", true);
        monster.style.opacity = "0.5";
        audioElement .muted = true;
    } else {
        button.setAttribute("isMuted", false);
        monster.style.opacity = "1";
        audioElement.muted = false;
    }
}

setButtonAttributes() {
    let iter = 0;
    for(let button of buttons) {
        button.setAttribute("monster", `monster${iter++}`)
        button.setAttribute("audio", `audio${iter++}`)
    }
}

setButtonAttributes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to populate your Arrays with the correct values (all = true at start) for your boolean Array, the references in monsters Array...

The last function `function resetToTrue(index)` update the boolean Array and avoid to have more than one monster not muted.

TAKE CARE : Click on "Full page" when you run the snippet if you do not want to see the logs over your buttons, they will not be clickable otherwise!

Have a nice day.

```js
        let nbElements = 7;
        let monsters=[];
        let buttons=[];
        let isMuted=[];
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",createTables);
        function createTables(){
            for(var i = 0; i < nbElements; i++){
                monsters.push(document.getElementById("monster_" + (i+1)));
                buttons.push(document.getElementById("button_" + (i+1)));
                isMuted.push(true);
                monsters[i].textContent = "monster n°" + (i+1) + " muted = " + isMuted[i] + " audio_" + (i+1) + " = " + !isMuted[i];
                monsters[i].style.opacity = 0.5;
                buttons[i].addEventListener("click",buttonClickHandler);
            }
        }
        function buttonClickHandler(e){
            isMuted[this.value-1] = !isMuted[this.value-1];
            monsters[this.value-1].textContent = "monster n°" + this.value + " muted = " + isMuted[this.value-1] + " audio_" + this.value + " = " + !isMuted[this.value-1];
            
            resetToTrue([this.value-1])
        }
        function resetToTrue(index){
            for(var j = 0; j < nbElements; j++){
                if(isMuted[j]==false){
                    isMuted[j]=true;
                    isMuted[index]=false;
                }
                monsters[j].textContent = "monster n°" + (j+1) + " muted = " + isMuted[j] + " audio_" + (j+1) + " = " + !isMuted[j];
                if(isMuted[j]){
                    monsters[j].style.opacity = 0.5;
                }else{
                    monsters[j].style.opacity = 1;
                }
            }
            console.log("isMuted Array = " + isMuted);
        }
```

```html
    <div id="monster_1">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_2">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_3">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_4">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_5">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_6">monster</div>
    <div id="monster_7">monster</div>
    <button id="button_1" name="button_1" value="1">button_1</button>
    <button id="button_2" name="button_2" value="2">button_2</button>
    <button id="button_3" name="button_3" value="3">button_3</button>
    <button id="button_4" name="button_4" value="4">button_4</button>
    <button id="button_5" name="button_5" value="5">button_5</button>
    <button id="button_6" name="button_6" value="6">button_6</button>
    <button id="button_7" name="button_6" value="7">button_7</button>
```

If multiple monsters may be "un-muted" , just comment those lines in the function `resetToTrue()` like this :

```
/*
if(isMuted[j]==false){
    isMuted[j]=true;
    isMuted[index]=false;
}
*/
```

Comment: @finn.trn, let me know if this is what you expected.

Comment: it probably should help me however I'm very much a beginner and don't understand most of the things you use to make it work. But still thank you for your answer! I'm going to do a little research on these things to see if I manage to get the hang of it before my deadline!

Comment: @finn.trn don't hesitate if You have problems with parts of this code...